# Match function to find the cell entered today's date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the match function the locate the cell entered the date of today.
Today's date is 22 April 2022, I need the Macro to return the value as 4 in below excel sheet.
Below are my codes, and it shows the error message "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class."
Can you please help me to fix the codes? Many thanks

```
Sub FindDate()

Dim FindDate As Long

FindDate = WorksheetFunction.Match(Date, Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)

Debug.Print FindDate


End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw an error if it doesn't find a match. And that is what is happening here:

If you search for `Date` it doesn't find the value because dates in Excel are stored in the cell as number of days since `1900-01-01` and the value is of type `Long` (or `Double` if it contains a time). Therefore you need to search for `CDbl(Date)` if you look for dates.

```
Sub FindDate()
    Dim FindDate As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next  'hide error message if match doesn't find anything
    FindDate = WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(Date), Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)
    On Error Goto 0  're-activate error reporting !!!

    If FindDate > 0 Then
        Debug.Print FindDate
    Else
        MsgBox "Date was not found!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the match function to locate the cell on another workbook "Book2.xlsx". The codes are written in Book1, and I changed the codes to "FindDate = WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(Date), Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)". It shows me error message "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method". What else do I need to do to make it work? Thanks

Comment: @Hazel Note that `Sheet1` and `Worksheet("Sheet1")` are totally different things. If you work with another workbook call the worksheet by its tab name `Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheet("Sheet1").Rows(1)` instead of its VBA name.

Answer (score -1):

`Match` is a member of the `WorksheetFunction` class, but you need to call it with an object.  Use

```
FindDate = Application.Match(Date, Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It shows a different error message "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"